# Separate and split a string with tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with values that are separated by  tags. How can I split that into three columns in SQL Server. These columns should be namely 'Application', 'Access Level', and 'Restrictions' containing corresponding text as text values. I am using SQL Server Management System 2012.

Below is what the value looks like that I am trying to split:

`<b>Application</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/><b>Access Level</b> : CLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. <br/><b>Restrictions</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.`

My code attempt:

```
select 
substring(ColumnName,1,charindex('br/><b>Access Level</b> : ',ColumnName)-1) as 'Application',
substring(ColumnName,charindex('<br/><b>Access Level</b> : ',ColumnName)+1,len(ColumnName)) as 'Access Level',
substring(ColumnName,charindex('<br/> <b>Restrictions</b> : ',ColumnName)+1,len(ColumnName)) as 'Restrictions' 
from TableName
```

Comment: Hi Dale, my code was really bad. But I will post it here if that helps my case

Comment: You really need a [mre] with sample data (formatted as tabular text) and desired results (also as formatted tabular text). I for one can't work out what your data looks like.

Comment: Actually show us your desired results (and your best attempt so far).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I have just posted my code attempt.

Comment: Show your desired results and you'll have a complete question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Assuming that you have SQL Server 2016 or later.

Your data closely resembles JSON:

1. Convert input column into a legit JSON.
2. Use `JSON_VALUE()` function to retrieve name/value pairs one by one.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, unstructured NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (unstructured) VALUES 
('<b>Application</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/>
<b>Access Level</b> : CLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. <br/>
<b>Restrictions</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, unstructured
    , JSON_VALUE(JSON, '$.Application') AS [Application]
    , JSON_VALUE(JSON, '$."Access Level"') AS [Access Level]
    , JSON_VALUE(JSON, '$.Restrictions') AS [Restrictions]
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('{' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(unstructured
    ,'<b>', '"')
    ,'</b> : ', '":"')
    ,'<br/>', '",') + '"}'
    )) AS R(JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much there, you just needed to debug your logic and add/subtract the right amounts in your substring to match your data. Thats assuming your data always follows that pattern of course.

```
select ColumnName
    , substring(ColumnName,22,charindex('<br/><b>Access Level</b> : ',ColumnName)-22) as 'Application'
    , substring(ColumnName,charindex('<br/><b>Access Level</b> : ',ColumnName)+27,charindex('<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : ',ColumnName)-charindex('<br/><b>Access Level</b> : ',ColumnName)-27) as 'Access Level'
    , substring(ColumnName,charindex('<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : ',ColumnName)+27,len(ColumnName)) as 'Restrictions' 
from (
  values ('<b>Application</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/><b>Access Level</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.')
) x (ColumnName);
```

I would tend to split this out using `cross apply` to avoid repeating the same calculation.

```
select a.ColumnName
    , substring(a.ColumnName, c.StartFirstString, d.LengthFirstString)
    , substring(a.ColumnName, c.StartSecondString, d.LengthSecondString)
    , substring(a.ColumnName, c.StartThirdString, d.LengthThirdString)
from (
  values ('<b>Application</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/><b>Access Level</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.')
) a (ColumnName)
cross apply (
    values (
        '<b>Application</b> : '
        , '<br/><b>Access Level</b> : '
        , '<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : '
    )
) b (FirstString, SecondString, ThirdString)
cross apply (
    values (
        len(b.FirstString) + 2
        , charindex('<br/><b>Access Level</b> : ', a.ColumnName) + len(b.SecondString) + 1
        , charindex('<br/><b>Restrictions</b> : ', a.ColumnName) + len(b.ThirdString) + 1
    )
) c (StartFirstString, StartSecondString, StartThirdString)
cross apply (
    values (
        c.StartSecondString-len(b.FirstString)-len(b.SecondString)-3
        , c.StartThirdString-c.StartSecondString-len(b.ThirdString)-1
        , len(a.ColumnName)-c.StartThirdString+1
    )
) d (LengthFirstString, LengthSecondString, LengthThirdString);
```

Both return (showing columns as rows due to the data length):

| Column | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Application | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. |
| Access Level | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. |
| Restrictions | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. |

Comment: Hi Dale appreciate the answer. I fixed my Query but the issue is that the characters don’t have the same length. Each row has different number of characters between the tags. Is there a way to instruct sql to query row by row in a dynamic manner rather than following a set length?

Comment: You need to show us enough sample data to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thats why a [mre] is critical, else peoples time is just wasted.